# Can one have no dharma?

Tags: dharma

How can dharma be determined, what if this is not apparent?
Is there a possibility for a being to exist without any particular dharma?

Comment: The belief is that everyone has dharma, a sense of duty. For example, as a son, you will have dharma. As a brother, you will have dharma. As a employee, you will have dharma. Everyone has multiple dharmas and one should decide to use which dharma at what times. Good question by the way.